# How to append row in tableview swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm adding data in my model and model is assigned to tableview to reload data. But every time reloading is not looking good. so I want just last element that was added in model, should be appended in already exist tableview. Tried so many ways but getting crash when my tableview is empty.

```
        let lastSectionIndex = self.isGroupChat ? self.objGroupChatList!.count-1 : self.objSingleChatList!.count-1
        var lastRow = 0
        if self.isGroupChat {
            lastRow = (self.objGroupChatList?[lastSectionIndex].count ?? 1)
        } else {
            lastRow = (self.objSingleChatList?[lastSectionIndex].count ?? 1)
        }
        let IndexPathOfLastRow = IndexPath(row: lastRow-1, section: lastSectionIndex)

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPathOfLastRow], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**This is crashing with error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table
>   view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the
>   number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Comment: Where do you add the item to the data source array? And – not related –  delete the `beginUpdates/endUpdates` lines. They are pointless.

Comment: You have to append to data to your datasource model first. Then call `insertRows` (`beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` are redundant )

Comment: I have added data into the model before inserting the rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0' attempting to delete row in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516970/error-invalid-update-invalid-number-of-rows-in-section-0-attempting-to-delete)

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala Before **appending/deleting** your cells, you need to make same changes in your datasource i.e. `self.objGroupChatList`

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have already added element in array

Comment: Add the code where you've added the element to array.

Comment: You say it crashes when the table is empty right? That is because you calculate your last row as (count - 1), if count is zero, last row would be -1. Make sure, it is not negative.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma Yes it crashes only when table is empty. With this, my last section = 0 and lastRow = 0

Comment: @PGDev added the function

Comment: So if your last row is 0, your IndexPathOfLastRow would be (-1,0). This is where it is crashing. Make sure, you don't create index path wrong

Comment: Did you assign a new array to your datasource when you put the first element? i.e. If you do `self.objGroupChatList = [[/*your first element */]]`, this error would occur since the datasource reference has changed. Make sure you never assign new object to your datasource and always modify it under the same reference.

Comment: @RickyMo yes the reference is same.

Comment: Try replacing `self.objGroupChatList = [elements]; let dict = self.objGroupChatList!.first!.categorise { $0.dtSendDate }` with `let dict = [elements].first!.categorise { $0.dtSendDate }`. I see no point to store it since you `removeAll` afterwards, plus this is changing the reference.

Comment: @RickyMo doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is you are creating new section. You should call insertSections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [insertSections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614892-insertsections) for new sections. insertRows only works for existing sections.

Comment: How would I get to know that I need to add section or row? I have multiple sections and rows.

Comment: Unfortunatly you have to write your own logic to compare your current data with the new data or keeping track of the progress before update.

Comment: If your data is only growing, you can simply check if the  section you intend to insert into exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like,

```
    let section = 0 //get your section here...
    dataSource[section].append("five")
    let row = dataSource[section].count - 1
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: section)], with: .none)
```

This is just an example of how you can get that working. Fill the gaps as per your code.

Comment: This is only what I'm doing. section = 0, row = 0