# How do I solve error 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0' in this particular case?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my `TableViewController` I get the following `error`:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Invalid update:
>   invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in
>   an existing section after the update (500) must be equal to the number
>   of rows contained in that section before the update (459), plus or
>   minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1
>   inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into
>   or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Now, this issue has been brought up in a number of cases here on `SO`, but since I'm not the least bit experienced with `objective-c` I find it hard to apply to my own code.

There's a tread here: [Error 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0' attempting to delete row in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516970/error-invalid-update-invalid-number-of-rows-in-section-0-attempting-to-delete)

and here for example: ['Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870680/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-rows-in-section-0)

Now my own code looks like this:

```
-(void)updateContactsStatusOnMainThread:(NSArray*)rowsToReload{

    if([sectionsArray count] > 0 && [sectionsArraySAEs count] > 0){
        //It crashes on the line below
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];  
    }
}
```

Having read similar threads, I still can't seem to understand what I'm supposed to do. Could someone point me in the right direction. I do understand the problem, as the error message is easy enough to follow. But how does it apply to my code? Does this concern `sectionsArray` and `sectionsArraySAEs` and how do I stop the error from happen?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you inserted some rows in to your tableView, but forget to add them in to your dataSource (`sectionsArray` or `sectionsArraySAEs` or some other).

First add item in to dataSource, then - insert row in to tableview.